# Set theory: $\forall A\;\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\notin A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is stated as a Proposition in my notes, and I honestly cannot see where this comes from. Sorry, I know it should be fairly simple, I just do not see it! The proof given reads

$\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\in A\leftrightarrow\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\subseteq\bigcup A$ -- this is a contradiction.

And I do not understand why this is a contradiction? I could prove it with foundation (see below), **but** we have not asserted the axiom of foundation yet; this proof follows from the axioms of extensionality, existence, pairing, union, power set, and the separation schema...

*Proof using foundation.* $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\in A$ would imply $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A)\subseteq\bigcup A$, and hence $\bigcup A\in\bigcup A$, contradictory to the axiom of foundation. This is because if $\mathcal{P}X\subseteq X$, then using that $X\in\mathcal{P}X$, we must have $X\in X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any set $B$, $\mathcal{P}(B)$ has strictly larger cardinality than $B$ by the diagonal argument.  In particular, $\mathcal{P}(B)$ cannot be a subset of $B$.

Explicitly, if $\mathcal{P}(B)\subseteq B$, let $S=\{x\in B:x\not\in x\}$, and then $S\in S$ iff $S\not\in S$.